# nodejs - request.get(url) returning binary data in case of yahoo.com

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http, encoding

I am trying to run the following javascript code.

```
request = require('request')
request.get('https://www.yahoo.com',function(err,res,body){ console.log(err ? err.message : body) })
```

But it is logging binary data whereas `html` string is expected.

The same code returns `html` response if I replace the first argument with a different url say `https://www.google.com`.

I have tried the same in ruby with following code

```
require('open-uri')
puts open('https://www.yahoo.com').read
```

It returns correct html response in both cases.

I think I am missing something while using `request` package of nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just see gzip-encoded html string. Use `gzip` option ([docs](https://github.com/request/request)) to get decompressed body.

```
request.get({url: 'https://www.yahoo.com', gzip: true}, function(err,res,body){ console.log(err ? err.message : body) })
```

Comment: Somethings we expect libraries to handle by themselves :D
solved the issue. raises a question though, why is it working with google then ?

Comment: I suppose, google watch your request's header `Accept-encoding`, but yahoo doesnt. If you debug headers, you can see that `gzip: true` adds `accept-encoding: gzip, deflate` to headers.